# Injectivity/surjectivity of the $\sin$ function restricted to the rationals

Tags: functions, trigonometry

A question out of sheer curiosity: is the map
$$\sin:\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
injective and/or surjective (on $[-1,1]$)?

Comment: Well, not surjective (cardinality is wrong).  Injective?  I think so...two values with the same sine would either differ by or add to an irrational number.

Comment: @lulu Good point for surjectivity. Thanks.

Comment: The edit didn't improve the last sentence... everything is "surjective on its image"

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks. I was reeally tired yesterday...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that $|sin(x)|\le 1$ so that $2$ is not possibly in the image. Infact, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is contable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, the image is nowhere near surjective. Though it is injective. This is seen as follows: If $sin(x)=sin(y)$, then $x=\pm y+\pi p$, then $x\pm y=\pi p$, so if $x$ and $y$ are rational, the number on the left is rational, so by irrationality of $\pi$, $p=0$, so $x=y$.

Comment: Yeah, I meant surjective on its image. I edited the question. Good point for injectivity. Now I feel stupid ;)

Comment: Not quite.  $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$ implies either $x = y + 2 \pi p$ or $x = \pi - y + 2 \pi p$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good catch! I edited the answer to reflect this. It is incredible how quickly you can forget your basic trigonometry.